# mysql properly construct a select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with ids and values. they are only unique together.

```
ID  VALUE
1   value1
1   value2
2   value1
3   value2
3   value3
3   value4
4   value3
5   value1
```

Assume I am given values "value2" and "value3", I want to select the ID that matches BOTH of these values (ie. 3)

I can

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE VALUE IN("value2", "value3")
```

However, it returns values that match either one as well. Is there a way to query ONLY those matching both of those values?

Comment: that's a horrible title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use GROUP BY with HAVING

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE VALUE IN("value2", "value3") GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE value = "value2" and id in (SELECT id FROM table WHERE value = "value3")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id FROM table AS t1 JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
  WHERE t1.value="value2" AND t2.value="value3"
```